# How to code - click an image and execute php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, hyperlink

Here's what I'm trying to do. Not too difficult for php and/or Javascript Wizards, but  really time consuming for me to wrap my head around. The site I'm working on will register a user and log them into a member content area.

Once they are in the member content area, I have an image as a link I need to code, so when the user clicks on the image, it calls a php file that executes which runs the authentication code (I already have the php file) and connects to a third-party website server HTTPS that authenticates the user, completes the redirect opens a new tab and logs them into a secure page at that site. Simple right? Not so much for me...

From what I've read so far, I've been seeing discussions comparing Javascript to Ajax and jQuery.

Does someone know of a simple Javascript script that I could tweak slightly that would execute the php file? Or what's the best straightforward method I should use here? Use HTML or what?

Any help is (greatly) appreciated!

Comment: As you indicate your skill isn't through the roof, I suggest you check out jQuery's `ajax()` (or `get()`, or `post()`). That will make things very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

What you can do actually is on click you can send a GET or POST request to a specific URL and the PHP script on that page would be executed.

For example;

```
$.post( "test/test.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

The data here is the results of the PHP execution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is **jQuery**! Nothing wrong with that, but if you expect javascript, you're not gonna get much result

Comment: Thanks to all that posted. Your posts got me thinking of a simple way to do this using Adobe Edge Animate to have Edge handle the javascript code for me. Very simple with one line of code.

Comment: Now just two small php files to edit and I'm done. If I post code can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest way to use jQuery, like this example:

(of cource before you need load the jQuery....js)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".img_button").on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          // do something with returned data
        }
      });
    }); 
  });
</script>
```